# Как передавать данные из контроллера во View в потоке

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Я каждые 10 мс отправляю запрос на localhost в котором передаю массив байтов. В картинку я его переведу, но как мне кидать на html, чтобы он обновлялся каждые те же 10 мс. Это мне нужно через контроллер изменять html страницу? Но я не знаю как это сделать, чтобы не возвращать клиенту обратно (через return), а выводить сразу на страницу, пусть даже на index.html. Проще говоря мне нужно чтобы контроллер изменял html страницу каждые 10 мс.

Comment: есть ли смысл обновлять браузер каждые 10 мс? Для потока сообщений я бы использовал веб сокеты, тот же SignalR

Comment: Ну контроллер врядли может просто взять и изменить страницу. Сделайте на странице элементарный скрипт, можно заюзать jQuery, закиньте его в таймер и пусть через GET запрос к вашему контролеру чекает есть ли новая картинка. Если есть  новая  картинка, запрос ее вернет, срипт обновит картинку на странице.